# Does the Star Wars original trilogy imply that Darth Vader aimed at deposing the Emperor with a converted Luke's help?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, darth-vader, darth-sidious, luke-skywalker

I am slightly rusty when it comes to all the details, but let me summarize my doubt and mention a few relevant evidences.

Throughout episodes V and VI, it seems as though Vader is seeking to recruit Luke *for the Emperor's sake.* Not only does he declare that intention in the Emperor's presence, but he also shows great loyalty to the Emperor throughout; he delivered Luke personally to the Emperor and blocked Luke's attack on the Emperor. Even till the very end, he watched on as his son was tortured, as though nothing could ever be more important than loyalty to the Emperor.

This couldn't have been Vader's ultimate intention though, or else it would go sharply against the original canon (now perhaps Legends) narrative, according to which Vader spent every moment of his life plotting against Sidious, and in fact was delighted to learn that he could now overthrow him with his son's help. Not only is this explicitly claimed in "The Rise and Fall of Darth Vader" by Ryder Windham, but it's also reminiscent of what he said to Padme: we can overthrow the emperor and rule the galaxy together, as a family. It would be very characteristic of him.

Putting together all the pieces, I barely doubt that Vader's final ambition was to overthrow Sidious and have Luke by his side. But is there a way in which all of Vader's words and actions in the movies can be clarified in this light?

Comment: "Join me and we can rule the galaxy together as father and son."

Comment: lots of relevant stuff in Related ---------------------------->

Comment: There are lots of related questions/answers you might want to read [1](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/114024/31936), [2](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/48866/31936), [3](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/178156/31936), [4](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/87486/31936).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A couple of direct Darth Vader quotes from *Empire Strikes Back* during their duel  pretty much state this explicitly:

> There is no escape! Don't make me destroy you. Luke, you do not yet realize your importance. You've only begun to discover your power! Join me, and I will complete your training! With our combined strength, we can end this destructive conflict, and bring order to the galaxy.

and

> Luke, you can destroy the Emperor. He has foreseen this. It is your destiny! Join me, and together, we can rule the galaxy as father and son! Come with me. It is the only way.

As you say though this is appears to be slightly contradictory to his actions in *Return of the Jedi* where he appears to be loyal to the Emperor:

> Not only does he declare that intention in the Emperor's presence, but he also shows great loyalty to the Emperor throughout; he delivered Luke personally to the Emperor and blocked Luke's attack on the Emperor. Even till the very end, he watched on as his son was tortured, as though nothing could ever be more important than loyalty to the Emperor.

His hope in *Empire* was that Luke would turn to the Dark Side and join him, Luke not only refused to do so then, showing a willingness to die rather than do so this refusal was only cemented when Luke was brought before the Emperor and refused to bend to his will.

Ultimately Vader's choice wasn't between loyalty to the Emperor and Luke but between the Dark and Light sides of the Force - Luke had made it clear he wouldn't turn so if Vader wanted to save his son he had to turn away from the Dark side.